# Trouble with zsh: command not found: code

Tags: terminal

I've been trying to make "code" work and open vs code, but using cmnd shift p and installing in vscode it self used to work until you restart the computer. Now even in vscode when I do, it's not working. I tried to change .zshrc to "`export PATH=~/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH`" which didn't work. What else can I do, when ever I type code it says "zsh: command not found: code". Thank you!

Comment: Changing your `PATH` will help, as long as you extend it with the *location where `code` is installed*. Where is it installed?

Comment: I'm new to coding so i don't know where it might be.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed vscode in the right way, i.e. via package manager, code should be in your path by default. Also, the bin folder in user's home is usually ~/.local/bin, So adding /home/[yourusername]/.local/bin might help (but that depends on how you installed your vscode and you may provide more information).

Comment: The `~/.local/bin` is a fairly recent convention, and not all distributions might not have it yet. The older equivalent would be `~/bin`.